# SSAS Referenced Dimension Issue

Tags: ssas, relationship, cube

In the most basic sense I have a fact table and two dimensions but my referenced relationship is only returning the top row for each CaseID.

1. FactTable
2. DimCases
3. DimCasesRepeating

All 3 tables are linked by a field called CaseID.

We have extracted data out of an XML into DimCases in column format. Most of the data in the XML only outputs once but some tags repeat, this can happen multiple times. Any of the data that repeats was extracted so that it goes into DimCasesRepeating and is not in DimCases.

DimCases has a regular relationship between CaseID & CaseID in FactTable. 
DimCases is then used as an intermediary table. A referenced relationship is created between DimCases & DimCasesRepeating on CaseID & CaseID.

The CaseID for DimCases returns ok but you only ever get one CaseID returned from DimCaseRepeating for each Case.

Eg. DimCases Table

CaseID, MainDetails

1,         England

2 ,        Scotland

3  ,       Wales

CaseID is only in DimCases once for each case but that caseID can be in DimCasesRepeating multiple times.

Eg. DimCasesRepeating Table

CaseID,   RepeatingDetails

1,        a

1,        b

2,        c

2,        d

If you choose 1 from DimCases & then pull across CaseID from DimCasesRepeating you only ever get one record.

OUTPUT

DimCases.CaseID,  DimCasesRepeating.CaseID

1, a

REQUIRED OUTPUT

DimCases.CaseID, DimCasesRepeating.CaseID

1, a

, b

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop using reference dimensions and start using many-to-many dimensions.

1. Create a DimRepeatingDetails dimension with RepeatingDetails a, b, c, and d. The table should include a RepeatingDetailsID column. Add this as a dimension in the cube.
2. Create a FactCaseRepeatingDetails table with CaseID and RepeatingDetailsID. Add this has a hidden (meaning the count measure is hidden) measure group in the cube.
3. Go to the Dimension Usage tab. On the existing measure group for your "FactTable" you mentioned in your question add a relationship to DimRepeatingDetails. But instead of choosing Regular choose type of many-to-many. And make FactCaseRepeatingDetails the intermediate measure group.

Now your report should work correctly.